# ASP.NET Core OData navigation property unexpected wishes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

On our project we use ASP.NET Core Web API, OData and Entity Framework Core. We have a case when table A has reference to table B. The main issue is that foreign key value does not exsisting in table B. Consequently, when we make OData request to get the navigation property of table A to table B, we receive broken JSON response with not filled navigation property. Due to it our customer raised a question. Is it possible to say OData to return NULL value for a navigation property if foreign key doesn't exsisted?

I know that is strange behaviour and it relates to inconsistent data, but we have such broken references a lot.

**Update**:

I've found out what the issue is. I'm trying to explain.

I have the following entities:

```
public class EntityA
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int EntityBId { get; set; }

    public EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I have EntityA { Id = 1, Value = "A", EntityBId = 1 }, but EntityB is not presented with Id = 1. So, when I try to make a request ~/odata/entitya?$expand=entityb($select=id,value), the request is not handled correctly, because OData can't set EntityB.Value to NULL. EntityB.Value is required.

Maybe I should remove ReuiredAttribute from IEdmModel. At this moment I don't know how to solve this issue when we have wrong foreign key.

I still try to find a solution. :-(

Comment: Does marking the relation as optional help at all?